# Javascript - how to get values from Text and form-group

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new in Javascript. what im trying to do is to get values from Text field and form-group, options.

Here is sample of my code

```js
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var type = document.getElementById("typeNotification");

function addButton(){
  var typeNote = alert(email);
  console.log(email);
  console.log(phoneNumber);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="typeNotification" class="form-control">
      <option>Shock Sensor</option>
      <option>GPS Jamming</option>
      <option>Ingition off</option>
      <option>Temperture</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control" id="exampleInputSMS" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter phone number">

<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

<button type="button" onclick="javascript: addButton()" id="addNotification" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Notification</button>
```

I saw few videos that this line *document.getElementById("typeNotification")* they add *.value* - for some reason it does not let me add it.
Any idea what should i do?

Comment: Use `.value` to get the value of an input.

Comment: Where are `phoneNumber` and `email` in the HTML?

Comment: I have tried that. but for some reason it doesn't working. i dont have that option.

Comment: it gives me nodeValue

Answer (score 0):

`.value` is the attribute you are looking for

```js
/** @type {HTMLElement} */
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");

/** @type {HTMLElement} */
var email = document.getElementById("email");

/** @type {HTMLElement} */
var type = document.getElementById("typeNotification");

function addButton(){
  // var typeNote = alert(email);
  console.log( type.value )
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="typeNotification" class="form-control">
      <option>Shock Sensor</option>
      <option>GPS Jamming</option>
      <option>Ingition off</option>
      <option>Temperture</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="javascript: addButton()" id="addNotification" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Notification</button>
```

**Edit:** Added docblock

Comment: I dont know why, but i cant .value, i dont have that option. it only gives me NodeValue. Have any idea why?

Comment: @E.Bolandian Who or what is preventing you from typing `.value` your fingers? :D

Comment: haha no, well i dont have that option. i type "." but it does not find  the *value* option

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: @E.Bolandian i edited the answer add `/** @type {HTMLElement} */` above your vars to tell VSCode which kind it is. It will be able to find `.value`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript statement document.getElementById("ElementID")  is used to get value from form elements.
Please specify what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way to do this**

If you just want to get the values of all the form elements on button click then use `value` to get the value of that element on button click

**or *for select box you can get the value like this also*:**

```
var myIndex = document.getElementById("typeNotification").selectedIndex;
var myOptions = document.getElementById("typeNotification").options;
```

***Here is the running snippet of your code***

```js
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var type = document.getElementById("typeNotification");

   
function addButton(){
  console.log(phoneNumber.value);
  console.log(email.value);
  
  //Use this
  console.log(type.value);
  //Or this
  var myIndex = document.getElementById("typeNotification").selectedIndex;
  var myOptions = document.getElementById("typeNotification").options;
  console.log(myOptions[myIndex].text);

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="typeNotification" class="form-control">
      <option>Shock Sensor</option>
      <option>GPS Jamming</option>
      <option>Ingition off</option>
      <option>Temperture</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter phone number">

<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

<button type="button" onclick="javascript: addButton()" id="addNotification" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Notification</button>
```

Also, I have made below correction

1. removed `var typeNote = alert(email);`
2. removed duplicate id `id="exampleInputSMS"` from phoneNumber field
3. removed duplicate id `id="exampleInputEmail1"` from email field

Answer (score 0):

Use the

`var index = document.getElementById("typeNotification").selectedIndex` to get the index of the selected entry

and use

`var x = document.getElementById("typeNotification").options` to get all the options

then just go through `x` like `x[index].text` to say what text the selected entry has.

[Here is a good Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_index)